# Authentication with facebook, twitter, etc.. all in one!

Tags: php, facebook, api, authentication, twitter

I want to allow visitors to connect to my website (like post comments or register) via major networks like facebook, twitter, yahoo.. Instead of manually implementing each one, is there a script or application comprised of all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out openID http://openid.net/developers/.  Also oAuth http://oauth.net/

Answer (score 0):

I came across to this.. http://hybridauth.sourceforge.net/ it includes a common API for major providers...